# C++, Симуляция работы автостоянки

Tags: c++

Добро времени суток!

Изучаю язык С++ в университете, нам задали сделать симулятор нахождения оптимального размера Автостоянки-обоймы.
Цель: Вам нужно написать программу, чтобы найти оптимальный размер стек-гаража и имитация действий.

1. Автомобиль идентифицируется моделью (например: «honda» volvo») и уникальный автомобильный  4- хзначный номер (например: 1212, 9999)
2. Автомобиль подходит к стоянке каждые X минут. X — это случайное число от 1 до 10 минут
3. Автомобиль покидает стоянку каждые Y минут. Y — случайное число от 1 до 12 минут
4. Автомобиль от разыгрывается случайным образом из числа всех автомобилей на стоянке
5. Если в одно и то же время приезжает новый автомобиль и предыдущий водитель хочет взять его автомобиль, прежде чем новый автомобиль заезжает, старый должен выехать, но перед этим, нужно вывезти все машины, которые перекрывают ей путь на поле возле стоянки(поле можно написать любым способом). Предполагаем, что это время занимает меньше минуты.

Программа содержит следующие классы:

1. Автомобиль:
   Этот класс будет иметь 2 свойства, передаваемые ему:

•   Модель – указатель на строку.

•   4-хзначный уникальный номер –const

В дополнение к этому свойство, содержащее запись времени входа автомобиля в гараж.
Реализованы следующие функции:

•   Констрактор

•   Деконстрактор

Вы можете добавить дополнительные функции по мере необходимости.

2. Парковка
   Размер передается во время создания и не может быть изменен. 
   Реализованы следующие функции:

•   Констрактор

•   Дестрактор

•   Push

•   Pop

•   Size – кол-во занятых мест

•   isEmpty

•   isFull

Вы можете добавить дополнительные функции по мере необходимости.

Основная программа
Выполнение симуляции  - день для парковки размеры: 6, 8, 10, 12, с тем чтобы найти оптимальный размер.

•   Оптимальный размер это когда в среднем за 10 симуляций кол-во уехавших машин из-за нехватки месте не превышает 5 машин.

Одна итерация:

• Получает размер стека.

• Цикл на протяжении всего времени деятельности парковки(с 8 до 14) (в минутах), и  будет разыгрываться время  прибытия и выхода автомобилей.

• При вхождении автомобиля на парковку, будет разыграна его марка и его уникальный номер.

• При удалении машины из парковки, будет разыграна случайно стоящая машина на парковке, если машина стоит глубоко внутри, то сначала выедут все впереди стоящие, а после выхода нужной машины вернутся в том же порядке в каком были.

К преподу обратиться не могу, так как он сейчас бастует и не знаю, когда вернется. Вот и пишу сюда.

В общем не знаю, если так можно было, распределил данные о машине на паркове в отдельные целые и строки, а не классом Car как планировал(нужно ли было), задание решил, если в будущем кому будет интересно, выложу тут.

Comment: _Как мне это обойти?_ - зачем?

Comment: "как мне создать симуляцию времени?" - что под этим подразумевается? Приведите пример.

Comment: Задача распечатать прибытие и отбытие машин. То есть рабочий день начинается в 8:00, скажем в 8:04 приезжает новая машина, но эти 4 минуты были случайно разыграны. Далее после 8:04 снова разыгрывается 1-10 минут, например новая машина прибудет в 8:09, в то же время в этот промежуток разыгрывалась в случайная машина, которая стоит уже на автостоянки 1-12 минут, и вышло 8:08. Я должен вывести все 3 машины, их номер, их марку и время

Comment: @Эникейщик потому что, я не знаю как еще мне можно создать автостоянку, подругому, я и пытаюсь это спросить, какие пути есть еще.

Comment: Зачем у вас места на автостоянке имеют тип ``Car``? Количество мест  - свойство самой автостоянки.

Comment: Но мне же нужно как то присвоить к месту сам автомобиль. А автомобиль сам по себе объект

Answer (score 0):

Определить классы можно так:

```
using Minutes = unsigned;
class Car {
    std::string* ps;
    const std::array<int, 4> n;
public:
    Car(const std::string& model, const std::array<int, 4>& number) : ps(new string(model)), n(number) {}
    ~Car() { delete ps; }
};

class  Parking {
    const unsigned max_size;
    std::stack<Car>* pc;

public:
    Parking(unsigned places) : max_size(places), pc(new stack<Car>()) {}
    ~Parking() { delete pc; }
    void push(const Car& c) { return pc->push(c); }
    void pop() { return pc->pop(); }
    unsigned Size() const { return pc->size();  }
    bool isEmpty() const  { return pc->empty(); }
    bool isFull() const  { return pc->size() == max_size; }
};
```

В стек ложится в конец и удаляется с конца, как требует ваша задача.  Теперь подумайте сами как написать симулятор и какие дополнительные функции понадобятся в классах

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду думать.

Comment: Не уверен, что нам можно пользоваться типом Stack, так же не совсем понял, как обходится разыгрывание номера во время создания самой стоянки и создание места под тип Car.  Так как номер const он требует у меня в конструкторе по умолчанию уже дать ему значение, но значение мне нужно ему давать только при въезде на стоянку.